# PHP - How to set full directory path in Content-Disposition?

Tags: php, content-disposition

I am passing a filename to a download page.
    **ie  somefile.xls**

The download page adds back in the full directory path onto the filename.
    **ie c:\temp\somefile.xls**

The problem is that now setting the 'Content-Disposition' of the header doesn't work.  The filename it wants to download is the full directory-filename path.
    **ie c_temp_somefile**

Can the Content-Disposition handle a full path?

If it can how do I get my script to properly download the file?

Code is:

```
$myad = $_GET['myad'];
$glob_string =  realpath('/foldera/folderb/folderc'). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$myad;

header('Content-Type: application/excel');
$headerstring = 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$glob_string;
header($headerstring);
readfile($myad);
```

UPDATED code (from answers):

```
$myad = $_GET['myad'];
$glob_string =  realpath('/mit/mit_tm/mrl_bol'). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$myad;

header('Content-Type: application/excel');
$headerstring = 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$myad;
header($headerstring);
readfile($glob_string);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't pass the full path via the header string, but use the base name (`$myad`) instead.

You should really use a better validation for `$_GET['myad']`, since your script will pass arbitrary paths to the user (`readfile()` gets the unfiltered user input). This is a security hole!

Calculate the real path using `realpath`, make sure that the file is within a allowed folder, then use `basename()` on the full path to get the plain file name. Pass this substring via the `Content-Disposition` header, but use the real path for `readfile()`.

---

**UPDATE:** Your updated code still contains a security hole. If `$_GET['myad']` contained `../../../some/full/path`, your script would happily send any requested readable file to the client.

You should use something along the lines of the following snippet:

```
$myad = $_GET['myad'];

$rootDir = realpath('/mit/mit_tm/mrl_bol');
$fullPath = realpath($rootDir . '/' . $myad);

// Note that, on UNIX systems, realpath() will return false if a path
// does not exist, but an absolute non-existing path on Windows.
if ($fullPath && is_readable($fullPath) && dirname($fullPath) === $rootDir) {
    // OK, the requested file exists and is in the allowed root directory.
    header('Content-Type: application/excel');
    // basename() returns just the file name.
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($fullPath));
    readfile($fullPath);
}
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It sure looks like it is indeed a significant security hole.

Comment: Ferdinand is right, that's a big security hole: a malicious user could download almost anything the web server can access (e.g. database passwords). About the Content-Disposition header, however, even with a valid path, the browser will still ignore it.

Answer (score 9):

You can put almost everything you want in the `Content-Disposition` header but most browsers, for security reasons, will ignore or replace paths and convert them to a valid filename for the operating system they're running on.

`Content-Disposition` is only a hint to the browser, it is not mandatory for the web client to respect this setting.

So, no, you can't force the download to a specific directory on the client computer.

Comment: Yep. In fact, the HTTP 1.1 spec specifically excludes directory path information from the Content-disposition header: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1

Comment: +1 - thanks.  makes sense - my code is for a intranet site so the security hole doesn't mattery too much.

Comment: Even if it's for an intranet, i'd follow Ferdinand advice: it's far better to avoid holes than to patch them later :)

Answer (score 3):

Never ever. If a browser accepts full paths it is time to file a bug, quickly: this would be a major security hole.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this would help, but I think that the content-type header for excel document might not be really correct, I have not tried it myself, but those microsoft packages come in a mouthfull, like mirosoft word is 
`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`